# Tell me who I am: To lead, she leads, daughter my

Tags: riddle, chemistry

I am not married, but a daughter have I
And to lead, she leads, daughter my
I was part of the li'l boy that once rocked history
I am just you, I ain't a mystery

Who am I?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is

> uranium

I am not married, but a daughter have I

> To quote Wikipedia, "A parent isotope is one that undergoes decay to form a daughter isotope. One example of this is uranium (atomic number 92) decaying into thorium (atomic number 90)."

And to lead, she leads, daughter my

> Thorium decays into other things which eventually decay into lead

I was part of the li'l boy that once rocked history

> To quote Wikipedia, "Little Boy was the codename for the type of atomic bomb dropped on the Japanese city of Hiroshima".  It was the first uranium-based nuclear explosion.

I am just you, I ain't a mystery

> The atomic symbol for Uranium is U (you)

Answer (score 5):

Who am I?

> Elena Tonra Lead of Band "Daughter" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daughter_(band)

I am not married, but a daughter have I

> Elena Tonra is not married but she has a daughter i.e the band DAUGHTER

And to lead, she leads, daughter my

> Lead singer of Daughter

I was part of the li'l boy that once rocked history

> To be deduced.

I am just you, I ain't a mystery

> To be deduced.

Comment: This is not quite what I was looking for...but a good attempt anyways

Comment: I don't get the "daughter my" part - how do you interpret / parse that in your answer?

Answer (score -2):

You are

> Uranium. Your decay includes lead Pb.

You were part of

> the Little Boy atomic bomb used on Hiroshima